# How I can put the title on the head on the left side and the name of the chapter on the right?

Tags: header-footer, lyx, fancyhdr

I'm working with Lyx, and I have the fancy style in the page layout. My document is printed on both sides. On the left side, I want to only have the title of the document and on the right the name of the chapter. Example:

```
Title of my thesis (left aligned) | Chapter 4. Chapter name (aligned right)
```

regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Document > Settings... > Page Layout, select the "fancy" headings style under Page Layout (also check "Two sided document" for a `twoside` layout):

[image]

To construct the actual headings, add to your document preamble (Document > Settings... > LaTeX preamble):

```
\fancyhead{}% Clear all fancy headers
\fancyhead[LE]{Title of my thesis}% Thesis title in Left Even header
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}% Chapter mark in Right Odd header
```

Comment: Thank you

Now, the title oh the thesis  it shows on white pages  (in the pages where is the index on the reverse, by example).  ¿How Can I remove the title of there?

One more thing. I can  make that pages say: 'page of total_pages', but, the number pages on the start de chapter only shows only the number page.

Best

Comment: @CarlosPérezLara: Chapter start pages are almost always set using `\thispagestyle{plain}`, which overrides your setting of `\pagestyle{fancy}` (selected under the *Headings style*). You could overwrite `plain` by adding the following to your LaTeX preamble: `\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhead{}% Clear all plain headers
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}% Plain footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
}
`. I assume you're also using the [`lastpage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) for referencing the last page...

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Werner's solution, you could do the following if you want a more native LyX way:

Go to Document > Settings and add "Custom Header/Footerines":

[image]

Then you can add headers as following:

[image]